# Sphinx Attributes Preserve Newlines to Html Line Breaks

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Is it possible to preserve newlines, or better yet, convert newlines in source code attributes to linebreaks in html when sphinx builds?

With this commented code

```
#: Sql string attribute documented information
SOME_SQL_STRING = '''
select * from a_table
'''
```

sphinx keeps the '\n' preserved in the string, and it looks similar to this:

```
<b>module.sql.SOME_SQL_STRING</b> = <i>'\nselect * from usr_table\n'</i>
<p>Sql string attribute documented information</p>
```

Ideally, we want the html to look like this:

```
<b>module.sql.SOME_SQL_STRING</b> = <i>'''<br>select * from usr_table<br>'''</i>
<p>Sql string attribute documented information</p>
```

I'm new to Sphinx, but have looked around and I'm not sure how to start going about handling this. I'm fine with writing a custom parser, but I'm not sure how to start going about that with Sphinx.

## How it currently looks:

**module.sql.SOME_SQL_STRING** = *'\nselect * from usr_table\n'*

Sql string attribute documented information

## How we'd want it to look:

**module.sql.SOME_SQL_STRING** = *'''
select * from usr_table
'''*

Sql string attribute documented information

Comment: Multiline strings are just a different way to create the same object; you won't ever see a `'''multiline string'''` in the output in the interpreter, you see the single-quoted version with literal newlines.

Comment: Yeah I know, having the sphinx html output surrounded with single or triple quotes isn't important. I know it's a niche problem, but we'd just like to see if it's possible for sphinx to parse the actual string and replace '\n' in the string with html <br> tags.